# How to create an optional generic method in an interface?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, abstraction

My Question is too simple, I have one `Interface` that contains one `method`

**Interface:**

```
public interface IAbstract
{
    void DoSomething();
}
```

I have two classes will contain the same methods in the interface, so I think to let them *(Classes)* implement the Interface.

**The problem:**
The only problem is in one of those classes this method will implement normally, but in the other class this method will implement as a generic method

**My idea as code:**

*First class:*

```
public class ClassOne:IAbstract
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

*Second class:*

```
public class ClassTwo:IAbstract
{
    public void DoSomething<int>()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I know that gave me an error, but my question ***is there any way to do what I think without creating separated interfaces ?***

Comment: No you can't because there is no way a user of the interface `IAbstract` would know that it even needs a generic parameter. Not clear what you are trying to do, as if `ClassTwo` already knows it needs to be an `int` why does it need a generic parameter? Or maybe you want to declare the generic parameter on `ClassTwo`?

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this:

```
public interface IAbstractRoot<T>
{
    void DoSomthing<TT>() where TT : T;
}

public abstract class IAbstractRoot : IAbstractRoot<object>
{
    public void DoSomthing<TT>()
    {
        DoSomthing();
    }

    public abstract void DoSomthing();
}
```

and children should be like this:

```
public class Child1 : IAbstractRoot<int>
{
    void IAbstractRoot<int>.DoSomthing<TT>()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Child2 : IAbstractRoot
{
    public override void DoSomthing()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this is just a mockup thing but my OCD is going to kill me If I don't point out the abstract class named IAbstractRoot.

Comment: There is no other way dear. Implementation of interfaces can only be GENERIC OR NonGeneric. "Not the both"

Comment: True but I meant the "I" prefix is a interface thing not an abstract class thing.

Comment: Yes, you are right. You shouldn't name it (Abstract)! Remove "I" and the "Abstract" keywords from all of the interfaces. It's will be the best. eg: change IAbstractRoot<> interface name to -> IRoot. and change the IAbstractRoot class to AbstractRoot.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign a generic parameter to the interface, then when implementing provide a concrete type there. To keep it generic just provide a generic to class b so you can pass it along to the interface, like so..

```
void Main()
{
    var a = new a();
    var b = new b<string>();
    
    a.DoSomething(1);
    b.DoSomething("Here is a string");
}

public interface IAbstract<in T>
{
    void DoSomething(T param1);
}

public class a : IAbstract<int>
{
    public void DoSomething(int param1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"I am specificly an int {param1}");
    }
}

public class b<T> : IAbstract<T>
{
    public void DoSomething(T param1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"I am a generic something {param1}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have several design options to get what you want.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var one = new ClassOne();
        one.DoSomething(); 
        var two = new ClassTwo();
        two.DoSomething();
        two.DoSomething<int>();
        var three = new ClassThree<int>();
        three.DoSomething();
        three.DoSomething(100);
    }
```

and the code

```
public interface IAbstract
{
    void DoSomething();
}
public interface IAbstract<in T> : IAbstract
{
    void DoSomething(T arg);
}

public class ClassOne : IAbstract
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("DoSomething()");
    }
}
public class ClassTwo : IAbstract
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("DoSomething()");
    }
    public void DoSomething<T>()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("DoSomething<T>()");
    }
}
public class ClassThree<T> : IAbstract where T : new()         
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("DoSomething()");
    }
    public void DoSomething(T arg)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("DoSomething(T arg)");
    }
}
```